# Firebase Organizing Membership to a Document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm creating an application in Firebase that needs ensure that users can only read/write documents/collections that belong to their team. My question is basically how should I structure the membership data. Specifically here is one idea I was considering:

```
/teams/{teamid}
{
   displayName: "Company X Team",
   owner: "userid",
   members: ["email1", "email2", "email3"]
}

/teams/{teamid}/projects/{projectid}
{
    name: "My Project"
    otherProps: "Other Properties"
}

/users/{userid}
{
    displayName: "John Doe",
    email: "john.doe@somedomain.com"
}
```

Should I store the "members" as an array as part of the /teams/ document (as pictured in the code sample above)? Or should I store it as its own collection of documents, much like the /projects/?

My main concern is when I go and write security rules. I want to make sure only the owner or members are allowed to make changes to /teams/ and its sub collections (like: /projects/).

Which way is going to be easier to write security rules for? Which one will have better performance?

Comment: Before you structure your data, you need to think about how you're going to query the data.  That's the most important thing.  Without knowing the queries first, the structure could be problematic in the future.

Comment: This is very true. I was formulating a query when I decided to ask this question. Specifically I wanted a query that would search /teams/ and tell me if the auth'ed user was invited to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would structure the members as a subcollection instead of an array. Make the document ID of each subcollection member the userID.

Then, you can just write a simple exists() security rule. This would also allow you to store additional data about the membership (are some members admins, when did they join, etc).

```
match /teams/{teamid}/projects/{projectid} {
      // Make sure a 'user' is a member of the team 
      allow write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/${teamid}/members/$(request.auth.uid))

}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Comment: I like that. However, now that I think of it, maybe I'll do both. I'll keep an array on the /teams/ document and call it "Invites" and store the email addresses. I won't have the "uid" until the person has authenticated for the first time. That means I'll need a rule that says something like: "You can't add yourself to /members/ unless your auth.email is in the Invites. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @ScottDietrich that sounds reasonable. Another approach for storing emails is to make another subcollection called "email_invites" where each document ID is an email address. I like this approach a little better because then it's easier to add/remove invites. Also, if you wanted some metadata attached to each email invite (like expiration date), it would be easier to accomplish if each email invite was a document.